# SQL/PHP I have the start and end locations but want to find the joining legs from a table

Tags: php, loops

I have a problem looping through my `tableLegs` for a bus timetable to find the array of legs `legID` that the passenger would need to take to get from a to b, take for example the passenger want to start at `LocID` of `c` and travel to `LocID` of `p`, I would like the array of legs that make up that trip `LegID`'s (`01`, `02`, `04`), hope that is easy enough to follow.

**tableLegs**

```
=============================================
LegID    startLocID   endLocID   departTime
 01          a           e        9:00
 02          e           i        10:00
 03          i           m        11:00
 04          i           q        11:00
```

**tableLegStops**

```
=========================================
LegID     stopNo    LocID     TripTime
  01         1         a       0 min
  01         2         b       20 min
  01         3         c       30 min
  01         4         d       40 min
  01         5         e       60 min
  02         1         e       0 min
  02         2         f       20 min
  02         3         g       30 min
  02         4         h       40 min
  02         5         i       60 min
  03         1         i       0 min
  03         2         j       20 min
  03         3         k       30 min
  03         4         l       40 min
  03         5         m       60 min
  04         1         i       0 min
  04         2         n       20 min
  04         3         o       30 min
  04         4         p       40 min
  04         5         q       60 min
```

To give you a basis for what I am trying to achieve here, it's for a bus website where each trip is made up of different legs.

Comment: i don't get it, why is that legID 3 is not included in your above, example? just what basis or logic do you apply from the result?

Comment: It's really messy and I think would just confuse the matter, but basically I find the LegID containing the start Loc ID (3), then check to see if the end Loc ID (18) is in the same Leg, if not I find the next Leg that starts the the endLocID of the firstLegID, I was just going to loop that, but I don't think this will work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: sorry @sephoy08 I should have said Start LocID of 3, where 3 is the stop the customer want to get on the bus at, and 3 is the 3rd stopNo on leg 1.

Comment: ok i get it so you make your cheking on `tableLegStops` and since, first item of `legID 3` there is not equal to the last item of `legID 2` you excluded it on the result. am I getting it right?

Comment: I've just changed the LocIDs to letters and LegID to have a leading 0, hope that helps clear things up!

Comment: hey i guess this part, seems irregular to me.
 `02         5          i        60 min` -
`03         1          i        0 min`

Comment: OK, so the bus leg (LegID 02) ends at the location (LocID i), and then bus leg (LegID 03) start at the same location (LocID i).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18898/discussion-between-user1335562-and-sephoy08)

Comment: i made a beta query for this, but it somehow messy and need to be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is known as searching for a shortest path in a graph. There exists an implementation of [Dijkstra algorithm](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#766) for solving this in terms of MySQL stored procedure.

But this would probably require from you to change your table structure a bit, because the graph uses only two types of entities: nodes and edges. So you should decompose your legs into edges, and then deduce the legs back after you get the shortest path in edges.

Comment: I believeI have the leg edges in the tblLegs, I would just add a step to check that leg to see if the end location stop is in that leg, However I don't want to only find the quickest I would like to list the options, I know in the above example there is only one possible route but that won't be the case when the table is filled out. Interesting read however!

Comment: @user1335562, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254151/directed-acyclic-graph-find-all-paths-from-a-specific-node) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Stan this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the A* search algorithm for this. Se http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star

Comment: This would be a better answer if it detailed what to do.